# can't generate the foreign keys in mysql ddl generation with PD9

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, powerdesigner

i'm using PD9.5. i'm generating ddl for mysql 3.23.but under the "generate database" below, in the "keys & indexes" tab, i dont have "create foreign key" option checked and i cant do it. but when i change the target to oracle 9i, i get the foreign key checkbox enabled.

[image]

under the "reference properties" i can't select restrict for update constraint option.

[image]

any ideas please about this bug ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you seriously trying to use MySQL 3.23? That software came out in 1999, and the last update was in 2003. You can't even get MySQL 3.23 anywhere. I found a copy of the source code and tried to build it a couple of years ago, and it was not possible. Some libraries it depends on are not backward-compatible that far back.

Comment: Now that I think about it, Oracle 9i and PowerDesigner 9.5 also both date back to 2001. I don't think you're going to get much help on these products.

Comment: As for the error, it is probably explained by the fact that MySQL versions that long ago didn't support foreign keys.

Comment: From the 3.23 DBMS definition for PowerDesigner, in the `Script > Objects > Reference > Enable` item, "References in MySQL [3.23] are only present as script compatibility with other databases.".

Comment: thanks both for explaining me problem.